# Event is not triggering after class change

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have `<span>` which is changing its `class`, when I click on it and ad versa.

**HTML**

```
<span class="submenu_plus"></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.submenu_plus').on('click', function() {
    console.log('plus');

    // some not important code  

    $(this).removeClass('submenu_plus').addClass('submenu_minus');
});

$('.submenu_minus').on('click', function() {
    console.log('minus');

    // some not important code

    $(this).removeClass('submenu_minus').addClass('submenu_plus');
});
```

My problem is, that only first event is still triggering, when I am clicking on that `span`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you are updating class, You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', ".submenu_minus", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

---

However I would recommend you to use a common class the simply toggle these `submenu_plus` and `submenu_minus` class. If you want to check element has a class, you can use `.hasClass()`

*HTML*

```
<span class="submenu submenu_plus"></span>
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.submenu').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('submenu_plus submenu_minus');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that I didnt know.